Does the Greek word "pas/panta" in Colossians 1:16-17 mean all things or does it mean "all" and the word "things' was added to these verses?
If the word "things" does not appear in the Greek text, what reasons justify adding the word 'things" to these verses?

Which Greek text are you using, which translation are you using, and which of the four instances of the wording, within the two verses, are you referring to, please ?

While I don't exactly agree with the way @Dottard has presented his answer, I can certainly agree that adding, or indeed omitting, the word "things" does not change the sense but it's insertion not only smooths the English, it makes for correct translation. The addition of the word "other", in the NWT and their KIT, I find also to be correct, at least that is by implication, or should I say substantiation. + 1 for this Q. although a further clarifying edit (for NJ) would not go amiss.

@OldeEnglish. The other question that made me ask this Q was about NWT's translation of pas/panta of Colossians 1:16. Can you please help me understand the body of that Q that asks "According to Jehovah's Witnesses, Jesus is part of the things created. Is this a correct usage of τα πάντα?" What does the NWT's usage of pas/panta have to do with Jesus being part of the things God created? If he really wants consistency, why would Paul call Jesus, if Jesus  really is the Creator, the firstborn/ firstborn of the dead in the context of genesis creation in Colossians 1:16?

If I understand things correctly, and to answer you, I see Paul "switching" from the Genesis creation, in Col, 1:15, where the Word, is identified as the firstborn of all creation in the beginning, who then aids in all (other) things created, in Col, 1:16,17, to after the death of Jesus, in Col, 1:18, where Jesus becomes the other beginning, and definitively, the firstborn from the dead.

@OldeEnglish. It was Adam who was firstborn if Colossians 1:15-16 is about Genesis creation.

Adam doesn't even figure in either of these scenes. He has his own scene, subsequent to that of the Word's.

@OldeEnglish. How can Colossians be about Genesis creation if Adam does not figure in the Genesis creation?

I didn't say that Adam doesn't figure in the Genesis creation. He absolutely does, also. We are being asked to go to "chat" here, but I don't think we need to do that. I'm also ready for bed at this time, at 12:33 AM, Monday morning.

In Col 1:16, the adjective πάντα (panta) does have "things" following - "things" is absent from the Greek text.
Now, in English, an adjective used as a substantive often (not always) sounds awkward and thus, the translators often add "things" to render the same sense into English that the Greek portrays. However, it is not essential - here is how I could translate Col 1:16, 17 literally but faithfully:

V16: because by Him [Jesus] was created all in the heavens and on the
earth, the visible and the invisible, whether thrones of dominions,
whether rulers or authorities; all through Him and unto Him have been
created
V17: And He is before all, and in Him and all consist

Note that panta = "all" occurs four times in these two verses: adding or omitting "things" does not change the sense but its insertion smooths the English.
Note that Paul goes to some trouble to remove any doubt that Jesus created everything in every class of "thing"; that is, "all" here really does mean literally everything and all.

If  Paul removed any doubt about Jesus  creating everything and all,  and that Colossians 1:16 is about the Genesis creation, why did Paul call Jesus the firstborn of the dead?

The wording is 'firstborn (or 'first-token') from among dead. A different concept and a different emphasis. Answer up-voted +1.

@AlexBalilo - that is a different question that has been asked and I have answered several times on this site.

@Dottard. I wonder if Paul really believed Jesus created everything and called Jesus the creator Firstborn,. It does not make sense.

@AlexBalilo - "firstborn" simply means most prominent - it is a common Greek metaphor.  There are several other answers on this subject here.  Paul certainly says that Jesus created all things.

@Dottard. Did Paul God the Creator first born?

@Dottard. Did Paul call the Creator Firstborn?

@AlexBalilo - yes - that is EXACTLY what Paul is saying - Jesus is the most important person to have ever risen from the dead, precisely because Jesus' resurrection enable's all other resurrections as per 1 Cor 15:12-21.

@Dottard. That is what you said, not what Paul said. Paul never called the Creator Firstborn or firstborn of the dead. God does not die. God does not need to be made alive again.

@AlexBalilo - sorry - that is exactly what Paul does say.  In Col 1:15 he calls Jesus the firstborn over all creation; the in V16, 17 he calls him the creator of everything (that makes Jesus the creator!!); and in V18 he calls him the firstborn of the dead.  It could not be much plainer!!

@Dottard. What is plain is the contradiction that your explanation creates. There's nothing about a second god that created, Deuteronomy 32:6, Isa. 44:24. If Jesus is the first born , then Jesus is not the Creator Jesus himself said he was born, God does not die and have to be given life.

@AlexBalilo - then you need to explain what Col 1:15-18 is talking about.  I see no contradiction with Jesus being "God" as John 1:1 and Matt 1:23 states.  There is only one God.

@Dottard. Then post it as a question.



Colossians 1:16 ESV - For by him all things were created, in heaven    and on earth, visible and invisible, whether thrones or dominions or rulers or authorities—all things were created through him and for him.


First, the word “πάντα” is the neuter plural form of “πᾶς” (pas), which means “all” or “every.”
Sure, the word “things” is not explicitly present in the Greek text, but it is implied by the neuter plural form “πάντα.”
Thayer's Greek Lexicon notes:

Neuter πᾶν, everything (anything) whatsoever;


It is also plural so let's focus on what Thayer's Greek Lexicon says on that:

Plural, πάντα (without the article): Taken in this form it can mean “all things” α.
of a certain definite totality or sum of things, with the context
showing what things are meant. Examples include Mark 4:34, Mark
6:30, Luke 1:3, John 4:25, Romans 8:28, and others.
Accusative πάντα (adverbially): This form can mean “wholly,
altogether, in all ways, in all things, in all respects.” Examples
include Acts 20:35, 1 Corinthians 9:25, 1 Corinthians 10:33, and
others.
In an absolute sense, πάντα: With this form it can mean “all things that
exist, all created things.” Examples include John 1:3, 1 Corinthians
2:10, 1 Corinthians 15:27, Hebrews 2:8, Ephesians 1:22, Colossians
1:17, 1 Peter 4:7, and Revelation 21:5.
With the article, τά πάντα; αα.: Given this form it can mean “all things
collectively, the totality of created things, the universe of
things.” Examples include Romans 11:36, 1 Corinthians 8:6, Ephesians
3:9, Ephesians 4:10, Philippians 3:21, Colossians 1:16, Hebrews 1:3,
Hebrews 2:10, and Revelation 4:11.


What we see then is that, in context, “πάντα” is used to refer to all created things, both visible and invisible. Although not directly used, “things” in English translations helps convey the meaning clearly to readers. The very nature of what is being referred to is everything in creation. In fact, several translations choose to translate it as "everything."
For example, the New Living Translation says:

for through him God created everything in the heavenly realms and on
earth. He made the things we can see and the things we can’t see— such
as thrones, kingdoms, rulers, and authorities in the unseen world.
Everything was created through him and for him.

The Christian Standard Bible even mixes them:

For everything was created by him, in heaven and on earth, the visible
and the invisible, whether thrones or dominions or rulers or
authorities — all things have been created through him and for him.

Personally, I think that "all things" is slightly better than "everything."

“All”: We understand that this word clearly indicates completeness or totality. It means that nothing is excluded.
“Things”: Specifies the objects or entities that are included in the totality.

To conclude, “all things” in the English translations provides the most clarity and ensures that the whole meaning of the original Greek text is accurately conveyed. “all things” captures the totality of creation, which is the intended meaning in context.

So pas/panta mean all physical creation? If these verses are about the Genesis creation, what sense is Jesus being the first born of the dead when there was no death yet during the Genesis creation?

@AlexBalilo Hmm. Yes, Colossians 1:16-17 is speaking of the original creation. I might not understand your question so correct me if I'm misunderstanding. To me there is a clear switch in the topic. I mean, in verse 18 Paul starts talking about the church. The church wasn't around in Genesis. The title “firstborn of the dead” refers to Jesus’ resurrection and His preeminence over everything.

If Colossians 1:16 is about the Genesis creation, and Jesus is the Creator, why did Paul call him the firstborn of the dead. Is the Creator the first born of the dead?

πρωτοτοκος εκ των νεκρων Col 1:18. It would be 'firstborn (or 'first-token) out of the dead but dead is plural, the dead. Therefore the idiom is 'from among dead'. Answer up-voted +1.

@NigelJ. If Jesus is the Creator in Genesis, it does not make sense for Paul to call the creator Firstborn or Firstborn of the dead.

@AlexBalilo   The Logos is he by whom God created. Also, God was the Logos. This, all, in the beginning. But, in incarnation, He who created is manifest in humanity and in this humanity he rises from the dead - a new birthing. This is very, very clear from scripture.

@NigelJ. What is very very clear is what you said is a postulation that contradicts the clear teaching that God does not change from spirit to flesh.

@AlexBalilo God was manifest in flesh 1 Timothy 3:16 [TR]. No, he does not change from one to t'other.  Thus God is among us, Emmanuel, in humanity.

@NigelJ. How is from siprit to flesh not change. How is invisible to visible not change? Is the Immanuel in Isaiah God too?

@AlexBalilo I'm sorry. I did not understand the last comment. Perhaps we should close this, now. And I think I have said all I wish to.
